# angularjs,restapi,springsecurty,hibernate any application

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest, spring-security, integration

I wanted to develop web application using below technologies

AngularJS+Spring Security+RestAPI+Hibernate

Could any one suggest /provide code for integration between these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

check out this sample application https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity